# Python - Comparing two lists to make a third list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, and I have a specific logic task that I'm not sure how to implement. Here are the lists:

```
list_1 = [826, 829, 830, 834, 837, 838, 842, 845, 846, 850]

list_2 = [826, 834, 842, 850]
```

list_2 is a subset of list_1.

The task I need is to make a list_3 using only the values in list_1 that precede the values in list_2. So it would be the list_1 items preceding 834, 842, and 850 (skipping 826 since nothing precedes it):

```
# Thus, we would end up with: 
list_3 = [830, 838, 846]
```

This is a bit of a specific logic question if anyone has the chops to help me out.
Much appreciated!

Comment: what did you try ? Where is your code?

Comment: maybe you should start with `for item in list_2` and later use `list_1.index(item)` to get its position and later get `list_1[position-1]` if `position-1 >= 0`

Comment: Do you only have unique values in each list? If not, can you give an example of the behavior? Are the values always sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with `for item in list_2` to work with every elements form `list_2` separately, and use `list_1.index(item)` to get its position on other list, and put on `list_3` item `list_1[position-1]` if `position-1 >= 0` (or if `position > 0`)

```
list_1 = [826, 829, 830, 834, 837, 838, 842, 845, 846, 850]

list_2 = [826, 834, 842, 850]

list_3 = []

for item in list_2:
    position = list_1.index(item)
    if position > 0:  # if position-1 >= 0:
        predecessor = list_1[position-1]
        list_3.append(predecessor)
        print(predecessor)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple solution I can learn from

Answer (score 1):

if they're in the same order, you can solve it in one pass using two pointers, like

```py
j = 0
list_3 = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i]==list_2[j]:
        if i>0:
            list_3.append(list_1[i-1])
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no repeted elements in list_1:

```py
list_1 = [826, 829, 830, 834, 837, 838, 842, 845, 846, 850]

list_2 = [826, 834, 842, 850]

list_idx = [list_1.index(x) - 1 for x in list_2]
list_idx = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, list_idx))

list_3 = [list_1[x] for x in list_idx]
```

If list_1 can have repeted elements:

```py
list_idx = [
    idx - 1 for idx, value in enumerate(list_1) for item2 in list_2 if value == item2
]
list_idx = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, list_idx))

list_3 = [list_1[x] for x in list_idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have unique items in list_1, you can use a dictionary to map the previous values. The complexity is `O(n)`:

```
d = dict(zip(list_1[1:], list_1))
list_3 = [d[x] for x in list_2 if x in d]
```

Output: `[830, 838, 846]`

Intermediate `d`:

```
{829: 826, 830: 829, 834: 830, 837: 834, 838: 837, 842: 838, 845: 842, 846: 845, 850: 846}
```

*NB. If you can have duplicates in `list_1`, then it is possible to generalize by using a dictionary of lists, but the expected behavior should be defined.*

Answer (score 0):

lists in python can be converted to sets as well, so you don't have to worry about n^2 duration.

```
list_3 = [list_1[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(list_1)) if list_1[i] in list_2 and list_1[i - 1] not in set(list_2)]
```

or

```
list_3 = [list_1[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(list_1)) if list_1[i] in set(list_2)]
```

if you dont care that the previous item could be in list_2 also.

Comment: `range(1,list_1)` is invalid - did you mean `range(1,len(list_1))`?

Comment: "lists in python can be searched as sets as well, so you don't have to worry about n^2 duration" - no, they can't. Looking up a value in a list implies iterating on the list, so it's O(n), while the same in a set is O(1). So this makes your code about O(n*n).

Comment: That’s right, `in` for a list is O(n).